# Etymology of "non capisce un'acca"

Tags: idioms, etymology

Where does the phrase "non capiscono un'acca" (meaning "they are stupid") come from?

I understand that "acca" may mean the letter "H", but I am not sure why not "understanding" it may be symptom of not being very smart...

Maybe it comes from "accidente"? In which case, why would it mean what it means?

Comment: http://archiviostorico.corriere.it/2004/agosto/05/lettera_che_non_conta_nulla_co_9_040805080.shtml

Comment: As for "accidente", I suppose it's intended in Aristotle's meaning, opposed to "sostanza". A person that doesn't even understand accidents (which are supposed to be of relative importance and little complication) is someone that has a very limited mind, and for sure cannot understand the substance of things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Frase fatta capo ha. Dizionario dei modi di dire, proverbi e locuzioni di italiano](http://books.google.se/books/about/Frase_fatta_capo_ha_Dizionario_dei_modi.html?id=4BZbPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) di Giuseppe Pittàno (Zanichelli, 2009, p.202):

> L'identificazione *h* con *niente* è dovuta al fatto che in latino la lettera *h*, in origine aspirata, pian piano si attenuò fino al perdere il valore di aspirazione. *Non capire un'acca* quindi significa *non capire niente*.
>
> **Translation**: Identification of the *h* with "nothing" comes from the fact that, in Latin, the letter *h*, at first aspirate, has gradually muted. *Non capire un'acca* means "(to) not understand anything at all."

Comment: e che significa 'frase fatta capo ha'? Is it an idiom?

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis *Frase fatta capo ha* is the title of the cited book and a play on words. There is a proverb *cosa fatta capo ha* (literally: "a deed done has an end"), meaning that what's done can't be undone and should have its consequences (more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidei) and [here](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_7/interventi/2253.shtml)). At the same time, *frase fatta* means "idiom, cliché." The author, Giuseppe Pittàno, has combined two sayings in one witty title.

Comment: "frase fatta capo ha" is the title of the book @i-m quoted (http://www.anobii.com/books/Frase_fatta_capo_ha/9788808161444/01510ce09772582c1e/). The title of the book is a pun of the idiom: "cosa fatta capo ha".